# How to use CiviCRM contact data latitude and longitude in drupal gmap formatted view

Tags: views, google-maps, civicrm

**Environment**
Drupal 7.67
civicrm 7.x-5.13.4
GMap Module 7.x-2.11
Location 7.x-3.7
Views 7.x-3.23

**What is working**
I have CiviCRM contact data for organisations which has been successfully geocoded using google
I have view in Drupal that can access and display this contact data in a table including company names and latitude and longitude
I can display a google map in the contact record in CiviCRM, so I know the Lat & Long is correct

**Problem**
When I change from a table to a gmap format in the view no map is displayed,

View setup

> Format Format:GMap | Settings Show:Fields | Settings open Add Fields
>   CiviCRM Website: Website URL (Website) CiviCRM Contacts: Contact ID
>   CiviCRM Contacts: Organization Name (Retailer) CiviCRM Address: Full
>   Street Address (Address) CiviCRM Address: Postal Code (Postcode)
>   CiviCRM Phone Details: Phone (Phone) CiviCRM Tags: Name (Name) CiviCRM
>   Custom: Organisation Fields: LALG Member Benefits (LALG Member
>   Benefits) CiviCRM Address: Latitude (Latitude) CiviCRM Address:
>   Longitude (Longitude)

GMap format settings

> Grouping field Nr.1
>
> You may optionally specify a field by which to group the records.
>   Leave blank to not group. Macro [gmap ] Enter a macro. If left
>   unchanged, it takes the default settings from
>   /admin/config/services/gmap. See the documentation on GMap macros.
>   Data Source
>
> Latitude field -> Latitude
>
> Format must be degrees decimal. Longitude field -> Longitude
>
> Format must be degrees decimal. Marker handling

I am also log messages when executing the view:

> php   Fri 7 Jun - 10:43am Notice: Array to string conversion in strtr()
>   (line...  gjw
>   php   Fri 7 Jun - 10:43am Notice: Array to string conversion in strtr()
>   (line...  gjw
>   php   Fri 7 Jun - 10:43am Notice: Array to string conversion in strtr() 
>   line...   gjw
>   php   Fri 7 Jun -> 10:43am Notice: Array to string conversion in strtr() 
>   (line...  gjw

Details

> Type  php Date    Friday, 7 June 2019 - 10:43am User  gjw
>   Location https://ref.lalg.org.uk/admin/structure/views/view/retailers/edit/retailers?destination=retailers
>   Referrer  https://ref.lalg.org.uk/retailers Message   Notice: Array to
>   string conversion in strtr() (line 1835 of
>   /var/sites/r/ref.lalg.org.uk/public_html/includes/bootstrap.inc).
>   Severity  notice

Answer (score 0):

There is a good recipe for using leafhttps://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/12862/how-to-put-your-civicrm-contacts-on-a-leafleft-map-in-5min if you are happy to slightly switch track. For D7

Also you will get more Civi eyeballs if you post on that channel, and while I appreciate this is a 'drupal' question, more civi folk use drupal than drupal folk use civi ;-). Good luck

Comment: Thanks Peter, I had seen leaflet map option, my data is UK based, and I am using locale for that which may create some issues. I would prefer google as the mapping source if I can make it work.